# How to deploy my Spring MVC web application using the build classes or war file into the Apache tomat dir?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am new to `Spring MVC Framework`. Recently I have learned to deployed the simple `web application` created using `JSP/Servets` in `Apache tomcat`. I have created a sample `web application` and successfully deployed it in `Apache tomcat`. For deploying I did following-

I have downloaded the `Apache Tomcat` core 64 bit zip from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi. Copy that folder "apache-tomcat-6.0.37" to `Z: Drive` and extract the folder. I already had `Java 1.`7 installed on my system in `C: Driv`e. Created System Environment of `JAVA_HOME` and `TOMCAT_HOME`. Copy my sample `web application` into `apache-tomcat-6.0.37\webapps\` You can see the structure in the below image.

[image]

Now I have created the same above web application in `Spring MVC Framework` using Net-beans IDE and I am able to run the application over the web browser using URL- `http://localhost:8084/SpringWebSample/index.html`.

Now I would like to go live with this application and deploy it on my server into Tomcat directory according to above screen shot but I am not finding any easy deployment steps. Each link that I found showing steps to run the Ant build script to deploy the sample application.

can I deploy my `spring MVC web application` in the same above way like I did to deploy the `simple JSP/Servets web application`?

Is there any way to deploy my `Spring MVC web application` using the `build classes` or `war file` into the `Apache tomat dir`?

Please help.

Comment: Going by that directory structure, your application does not look much like a Spring MVC application. It's a web app with a single Servlet.

Comment: @Steve I did not get your point. Please elaborate. I am new to MVC Framework. Is there any different approach to deploy the Spring MVC application?

Comment: It's not a comment on how to deploy. I said it does not look like your application is a Spring MVC application. Certainly, whether or not it is a Spring MVC application is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Spring MVC application is a regular Java webapp which happens to use Spring internally. It's deployed like any other web application. So yes, you can simply take the war file of your Spring MVC app and drop it in `tomcat/webapps`.

Comment: Thanks but when I searched with the keyword `how to deploy the mvc spring framework web application in tomcat` I am getting all the hits that are saying to `run Ant build script` or `download the Spring Framework` from http://www.springframework.org/download. That creates really confusion. Can you please hep me to understand why to download spring frame work in step by step deployment of web application - http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html

Comment: JB did provide a step-by-step explanation of the deployment. Copy the war file into the webapps directory. That's it. Nothing more.

Comment: You must download the spring framework in order to be able to use it, obviously. But you already did that, since you're already using it. Professional developers like to have simple procedures to build and deploy an application. That's why tools like Ant, Gradle or Maven are used. Being forced to manually compile the classes, then generate a war, then copy the war, etc. is something that build tools allow avoiding. And this tutorial uses Ant to automate everything. But if you're fine with your way of doing, then simply copy the war file to tomcat/webapps.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. Is there any other approach to deploy the Spring MVC application using or NOT using Tomcat?

Comment: It seems you're missing key concepts of Java webapps. Java webapps can't run on their own. They need to be deployed inside a Java web container. You can choose another container like Jetty, JBoss, Glassfish, Resin, WebLogic, etc. But you will need a container.

Answer (score -1):

If you work with Spring 4 + gradle, you can leverage spring boot.
you can simply run gradle bootRepackage.

More inforamation about packaging as WAR:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging

To build and run a project artifact, you can type the following:
$ gradle build
$ java -jar build/libs/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

To build a war file that is both executable and deployable into an external container, you need to mark the embedded container dependencies as belonging to a configuration named “providedRuntime”, e.g:
...

```
    apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'myapp'
    version =  '0.5.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    ...
}
```